# Limiting access to a certain folder in debian

Tags: debian

I want to give access to a user for only two directories residing under my /var/www folder.He must have full rights of these directories where he can add new files, new sub directories, chmod, chown etc. How can I do this, I am on debian.

Comment: See this similar question on U&L for an explanation of filesystem permissions in Unix/Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/unix-users-groups-and-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods I can think of.  One add the user to a group that owns those directories, or alternatively, change the ownership of those directories to that user.

```
chown username name_of_directory
```

That will allow that user full rights to that directory.  On our servers we have a developer group that all developers are members to and all the necessary directories are owned by that group.
With group ownership you would probably be looking at a 0775 for the full rights.